# Xamarian Form preview Error

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My xamarian form previewer is not working for android.

I have already my JDK version-10.0.1[Screen shot my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XgNI.png)

Please help me

Comment: There is little to no information for us to recreate the issue. Please tell us what documentation did you follow. Or provide us with Xamarin version and Its inbuilt android configuration.

Comment: Xamarin   4.9.0.753 (f0f46392f)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.10.96 (a702a9ceb)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.16 (HEAD/a78295902)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: 1.Xamarin   4.9.0.753 (f0f46392f)

Comment: Hello every one , any help regarding this issue? I don't have mac device to pair it with visual studio.Can it be caused that my preview is not showing ?